# Why don't I get the same answer when I calculate the pullback vs integral over a manifold?

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds, differential-forms

Let's take the differential form $\omega = xy \, dx \wedge dy$. We say that $M$ is the surface $z = x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ with the standard orientation.

I can calculate $\int_M \omega$ via pullback and get: $=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r^3 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) \,dr \,d\theta = 0.$

I can also try calculating it with the generalized Jacobian and got $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r^3 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta) \sqrt{1+4r^2} \, dr \, d\theta = 0.$$

Obviously the result is the same but only because of the domain. I think that there's a mistake in my thinking somewhere along the way, and that the results should be equal (on all domains).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your "generalized Jacobian" expression seems to involve $dz$ (or the unit normal vector to the paraboloid) in some way...?

Comment: Yes. The manifold is given by the chart $\phi(r,\theta) = (rcos \theta, rsin \theta, r^2)$ and the generalized Jaacobian is the square root of the determinant of$ (D_{ \phi})^T(D_{ \phi})$

Comment: Yes, but to calculate the surface integral as a flux $\iint_{M} F \cdot \mathbf{n}\, dS$, you first identify $\omega$ with the vector field $F = (*\omega)^{\sharp} = (0, 0, xy)$, so the third-component dependence of the surface washes out.